# Texture Paint Strange Behaviour

Tags: texture-painting

I have just finished sculpting a character..

Will start texture painting it..

I have done this several times without any problems, but for this character the texture paint shows up on totally different spots than where I paint. I can't seem to figure out the problem. Has any of you encountered similar problems and found a cause?

In attachment Blend file and colourmap..

https://jumpshare.com/v/0iLa4sG3XPqRhm72OMXw (Blend File Link)

https://jumpshare.com/v/l18DphvIDGy2VVW7kmih (Colourmap, click on 3 dots to download)..
Map is not painted yet, but included it to be complete..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two UV maps for your model and have the wrong one selected for painting.

The first, "female_1_female_base.017DiffuseUVlayer" is the one one you want to have selected in the list **and** have its little camera icon enabled. The UV map with the enabled Camera icon is the UV map that will be used for rendering **AND painting**.

[image]

The second,"UV Map" is just a mess and it would be probably best to delete it from the list.

Comment: Damn, thanks a lot!